# Best way to store array of XY coordinates in SQL Server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, database-design, geometry, coordinates

I'm mapping out rooms on floorplans and set the boundaries of the room with coordinates such as `[[400, 175], [400, 200], [360, 200], [360, 175]]` consumed by a JS front end.

Each room is a row in the table and the boundary coordinates is a column.  How should I store this data for performance?

Store it as a string as is `[[400, 175], [400, 200], [360, 200], [360, 175]]` and deserialize it upon retrieval.

Store it as a CSV `400,175,400,200,360,200,360,175` and treat each pair as a coordinate to rebuild the array.

Store it as a `geometry` type? Not sure if this is applicable, never used it.

Comment: Depends how you plan to utilize the data in the database - if you're just storing it to retrieve it verbatim and won't need to search or filter it, store it exactly as it's passed in. If it's large consider enabling compression.

Answer (score 0):

Two options 1)You can stored as a JSON Array 2) Store as a Binary format which will be faster to retrieve compared to JSON